# How to undo (cancel) manual rotations with GeometricTransformation

Tags: graphics3d, rotation, geometric-transform

How to dynamically transform an object inside `Graphis3D` so that when whole `Graphis3D` is manually rotated by pointer the object stays stationary? (from the perspective of observer)

In the following code we have two objects inside `Graphics3D` - inner cube `incude` and outer cube `outcube`. I want the code to do cancelation of rotation of `incube` while whole `Graphics3D` is rotated manually. I tried to used rotation transformations based on values of `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` but it does not work because the `incube` rotates. What `GeometricTransformation` to use to cancel that rotation?

Variables `dvp` and `dvv` are default setting of `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical`, `vp` and `vv` are actual dynamic values of `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` that change on manual rotation.

```
{vp, vv} = Options[Graphics3D, {ViewPoint, ViewVertical}][[All, 2]];
{dvp, dvv} = {vp, vv};
outcube = Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}];
incube = Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 
   1/2}]; Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], outcube, 
  GeometricTransformation[incube, 
   Dynamic[RotationMatrix[{vp, dvp}] . RotationMatrix[{vv, dvv}]]]}, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
 ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
 PlotLabel -> Column[{Dynamic[vp], Dynamic[vv]}]]
```

[image]
[image]